# Error "Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration" en android studio 4.2.1

Tags: android, android-studio

Hola me pueden ayudar con esto, al tratar de construir/compilar mi proyecto obtengo el siguiente error:

> A problem occurred configuring root project 'newapp'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1.
> Required by:
> project :
> > No cached version of com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1 available for offline mode.
> > No cached version of com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1 available for offline mode.

> Possible solution:
>
> - Disable offline mode and rerun the build

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Si revisas los mensajes, indican el problema:

> Could not resolve
> No cached version of Possible solution: Disable
> offline mode and rerun the build

> No se pudo resolver
> Sin versión en caché de Posible solución: Desactivar
> modo fuera de línea y vuelva a ejecutar la compilación

**La solución es desactivar "modo fuera de línea"** ya que no tienes en caché alguna versión de las mismas y si trabajas en modo offline pues nunca se descargarán.

En el lado superior derecho de tu Android Studio en "Gradle" (elefantito) abre y podrás ver la opción para "modo offline", debes desactivarla para que descargue las dependencias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]